# MSBUILD generate only dll?

Tags: jenkins, msbuild, continuous-integration, iis-6

I have a problem with MSBUILD .
I want to automate the deployment of applications on IIS6 .
I use jenkins , I have a job that compiles OK my solution.
Then I want to create a copy of the compiled files in the directory IIS6 .

MSBUILD generate this :. C: \ Workspace \ RM *** \ bin \ dll ***

Why I have only one dll and not the complete solution?
MSdeploy is it took over in IIS6 ?

how to deploy the complete solution in IIS6 without WebDeploy ?

Comment: let us know what your msbuild project includes.  What targets are you calling?  How are your tasks configured?

Comment: When i build on my computeur with MSBUILD its OK : 

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>MSBuild C:\Applications\*****\****\*****.vbproj
Microsoft (R) Build Engine, version 4.0.30319.17929
[Microsoft .NET Framework, Version 4.0.30319.17929]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Tous droits réservés.

La génération a réussi.
    0 Avertissement(s)
    I do not understand why MSBUILD generates only a DLL file